# How can I connect to Kubernetes Job without service from other Pod through dns?

Tags: kubernetes, dns

I have Kubernetes job without service and I need to connect to it from different pod (not job) on the cluster. According to docs, I can do it only by using IP, but not with DNS as it has no service.
Will appreciate any ideas how to solve this problem